# asX vs toX prefixes for type conversions in libraries

Tags: java, kotlin, android-library

I am primarily an Android developer but the same rules should also apply to standard Java and Kotlin I suppose.

1. What is the criteria between choosing **as** (e.g asLiveData, asStateFlow) or **to** (e.g toString) for converting from one type to another?
2. And now my real question. I've made a couple of extension functions which convert a ByteArray to a hex String and vice versa. What nomenclature would make more sense?

`String.toByteArrayFromHex` vs `String.asByteArrayFromHex`

`ByteArray.toHexString` vs `ByteArray.asHexString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think these naming conventions in the Kotlin standard library are officially documented, but I've noticed some fairly common patterns.  For example:

- `to<Type>()` — **converts** an object to the required type, and returns it.  (The original is unchanged, and independent of the new one.)  [toString()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html) is of course the most common example.
- `as<Something>()` — returns a **view** of the object.  (Doesn't change the original immediately; however, later changes to the state of object will be reflected in the view, and, if appropriate, vice versa.)  For example: [asReversed()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html).
- `<verb>()` — **mutates** the object in-place.  (Doesn't usually return anything.)  For example: [reverse()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reverse.html).
- `<verb>ed()` — returns a **mutated copy** of the object.  (The original is unchanged, and independent of the new one.)  For example: [reversed()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reversed.html).
- `<xxx>OrNull()` — indicates that a method will return null if there's no valid value to return (instead of throwing an exception or returning some other default).

Like all conventions, there's nothing forcing you to use these naming patterns — but if you do, they'll fit more naturally into existing code, and people will find them more intuitive to use.

(Not all library methods follow these conventions; for example, `map()` and `filter()` are verbs, but don't mutate their receiver.  However, they long pre-date Kotlin, so it's understandable that they stick with the well-known existing names.  And JetBrains seem to be adhering more strongly to these conventions; for example, in Kotlin 1.4 they deprecated the [max()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max.html) function in favour of the new [maxOrNull()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-or-null.html).)

---

In your examples, `ByteArray.toHexString()` would be a perfectly good name, as it converts the array into a new type, without keeping any connection to the original.  I think anyone seeing the name would immediately know what it does.  (More or less, anyway; params or docs would have to specify details such as what separator it used, if any, and whether it used upper or lower case.)

Similarly, `String.toByteArrayFromHex()` is much clearer than the alternative, though I'm not sure it reads well.  How about `String.hexToByteArray()`?