# Sorting array with comparing

Tags: kotlin

I would like to find 2 values which occurs only once in the array, but using sortedArr[i] I get an error.
Do you guys know why? :)

```
fun repeats(arr: IntArray): Int {
    
    var sortedArr = arr.sort()
    
    var sum: Int = 0
    
    for(i in arr.indices) {
        if(sortedArr[i].toInt() != sortedArr[i+1].toInt()){
                sum += sortedArr[i].toInt()
        }
        }
    return sum
    }
```

```
@InlineOnly public inline operator fun <@OnlyInputTypes K, V> Map<out Int, ???>.get(key: Int): ??? defined in kotlin.collections
@SinceKotlin public operator fun MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in kotlin.text
                sum += sortedArr[i].toInt()
                       ^
src/main/kotlin/solution.kt:9:33: error: no get method providing array access
```

```
fun basicTests() {
        assertEquals(15, repeats(intArrayOf(4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 8)).toLong())
        assertEquals(19, repeats(intArrayOf(9, 10, 19, 13, 19, 13)).toLong())
        assertEquals(12, repeats(intArrayOf(16, 0, 11, 4, 8, 16, 0, 11)).toLong())
    }
``
```

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs? Your code is very different from what you say you want to do.

Comment: I edited main post, it's my input with assert Test. I'm doing it on codewars.

Comment: Replace `arr.sort()` with `arr.sorted()` and it will get compiled (`sort()` does in-place sorting, `sorted()` returns new array)

Comment: Alright thanks so I need to use something toList() thanks :)

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65676605/10134209) which explains this sort of naming convention.

Comment: I understand your approach to finding a unique value, but the implementation is wrong :-) Note that if you have e.g. `[4,4,4,4,5,5,5]` then `4` will still be selected as unique, because when `i = 3` then you compare `4` and `5`. You would need to compare to both adjacent values, not only to the next one. Also, for the last element `sortedArr[i+1]` will get out of bounds. You need to stop one item earlier and add a special case for the last item (same for the first one if you compare to both neighbours).

Comment: Thank you guys, broot that's is true. But in this specific exercise numbers occurs twice or only once. 
I just made 2* sum of set(numbers) - sum(numbersInArray)

I reread your message that's true I should use your advice here and compare to previous number as well :)