# Sort a list with two different objects

Tags: kotlin

I need to have a list of List objects sorted.

```
Etape contains 
val etat: etat? = null
    val echeancier= Echeancier()

enum class Etat(val type: Int) {
        EnCours(1), Valide(0)
    }

 Echeancier contains a date value
val date: String? = null

"date": "2022-01-24T00:00:00"
"date": "2023-06-20T22:00:00"
"date": "2023-07-12T22:00:00"
"date": "2023-06-03T22:00:00"
```

I would like to sort the elements first by Etat , first all Valide(0) and then EnCours(1)

and sort these elements by date
then all Valid elements by date and then all EnCours by date

If I run the individual sortBy , the orders are correct even the date

```
listCompl.sortBy { etapes.etat } 
listCompl.sortBy { etapes.echeancier.date }
```

but if I then try to make the two conditions merge the order by date does not work

I have tried these functions I found on the net without success

```
listCompl.sortedWith(compareBy({ etapes.etat }, { etapes.echeancier.date }))

listCompl.sortedWith(compareBy<Etape> { etapes.etat }.thenBy { etapes.echeancier.date })

listCompl.sortedWith(compareBy<Etape> { etapes.etat }.thenByDescending { etapes.echeancier.date })
```

The first three are the ones with Etat Valide the others EnCours so the problem is on the ones in blue that are not sorted by date

> listCompl.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.etat }, { it.echeancier.date }))

[image]

I thought the problem was the date.

But if I only run a sortBy for the date, the sort by date is correct
where am I going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Did you store the result of `sortedWith()` anywhere? Please note `sortBy()` sorts in-place while `sortedWith()` returns a sorted list. Your attempted solution generally looks fine.

Comment: @broot In the printscreen that is incorrect I used the sortWith
listCompl.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.etat }, { it.echeancier.date }))

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You said you used `sortWith`, then you provided a code sample where you use `sortedWith`.

Comment: It works with this, thank you
listCompl.sortWith(compareBy({ it.etat?.type }, { it.echeancier.date}))

Comment: If it helps, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65676605/10134209) explains some of these naming conventions used in the Kotlin standard library.